# Length of Longest increasing subsequence

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am not expecting for a solution here. But I have trouble finding out what could be a possible error. I feel that this is correct solution but however, the solution is not passing all the test case I have. e.g `{2,2}` . Below is the code I have written in a brute force (worst case - `n!` complexity) approach. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not expecting the solution but would like to know where I am going wrong and how to get it right.

```
 package org.practice;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class LengthofLIS {
        int maxLength = 0;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LengthofLIS l = new LengthofLIS();
            int[] nums = { 2,2 };
            l.lengthOfLIS(nums);
        }

        public int lengthOfLIS(int[] nums) {
            if (nums.length == 1)
                return nums.length;
            List<Integer> hs = new LinkedList<>();
            dfs(nums, 0, 0, nums.length - 1, hs);
            System.out.println(maxLength);
            return maxLength;
        }

        public void dfs(int[] nums, int index, int length, int end, List<Integer> hs) {

        if (index > end) {
            return;
        }

        for (int i = index; i <= end; i++) {

            if (hs.size() == 0) {
                hs.add(nums[i]);
                length++;
            } else if (nums[i] > hs.get(hs.size() - 1)) {
                hs.add(nums[i]);
                length++;
            }

            else if (nums[i] <= hs.get(hs.size() - 1))
                continue;

            dfs(nums, i + 1, length, end, hs);
            //System.out.println("Printing " + Arrays.asList(hs));
            maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, hs.size());

            if (maxLength == nums.length)
                break;

            if (hs.size() != 0) {
                hs.remove(hs.get(hs.size() - 1));
                length--;
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: On which platform you are submitting? What kind of error you are getting? Wrong answer or Time Limit Exceeded ?

Comment: I am trying on leetcode. i am getting a wrong answer.

Comment: It very difficult to find what you are doing in the code. Nobody is going to read your code thoroughly. You need to describe your algorithm.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar sometimes it is a good challenge to find out what is wrong with others code because you aren't in their mind to know what they are thinking and this make a good challenge :)

Comment: @Lrrr You are right that can be a good challenge.  HOWEVER, it is not what StackOverflow was made for

Comment: @AdrianShum yeah, you are right. jojo should've explained the algorithm behind the code. Then this could make more sense.

Comment: @Adrian Shum Sorry about that. i will write comments to explain the code. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't ask for any solution, I won't provide you one, and on the other hand, you could simply find lots of answers by just a simple search.

Here is what I understand from your code:

```
public void dfs(int[] nums, int index, int length, int end, List<Integer> hs) {
    if (index > end) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = index; i <= end; i++) {
        if (hs.size() == 0) {
            hs.add(nums[i]);
            length++;
        }
        else if (nums[i] > hs.get(hs.size() - 1)) {
            hs.add(nums[i]);
            length++;
        }
        else if (i == end && nums[i] < hs.get(hs.size() - 1)) { //(1) 
            maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, hs.size());
        }
        else if (nums[i] < hs.get(hs.size() - 1))
            continue;
        dfs(nums, i + 1, length, end, hs);
        if (hs.size() != 0) { //(2)
            hs.remove(hs.get(hs.size() - 1));
            length--;
        }
    }
}
```

1. what do you want to accomplish with that? consider the situation when the last element is the biggest element, then you will always print `0` because you'll never set `maxLength`.
2. your main problem is here. Because you remove `a[i]` , `a[i+1]` recursively from the list. suppose you have `{2, 3, 100, 4, 5, 6, 1}` instead of considering `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` longest list, your code will consider `[2, 4, 5, 6]` the longest list.

Comment: thanks for your input.Appreciate your effort in understanding my code & feedback. Point 1 is clear. Regarding the point 2, I wanted this not to happen. as soon as I remove the last element from the list, I wanted to add further elements after the index of the removed element. Suppose my list "hs" has [2,3,100] and it reached end to find out there are no more elements to be added, I backtrack to previous state which is [2,3] by removing [100].What I would like to do now is go further and add up {4,5,6} making it [2,3,4,5,6]. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @jojo No, your code won't do this. Think a little bit more and you'll understand why but if I were you I would try another approach. Soin my opinion read about existing algorithm and understand them, I just wanted to point out your mistakes. It is not a good idea to repair this code in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will think through and try to fix it. Appreciate your suggestion

Comment: @Jojo glad to be helpful, if you find it helping please upvote and mark it as answer

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have missed few edge cases which I have corrected in the original post.